# Migraciones en rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

¿Existe alguna forma de que al generar un **scaffold** por consola se pueda escoger el nombre de la tabla que genera la migración?, esto con la finalidad de trabajar con un mer diseñado en español.

Comment: Ya la tabla existe en otra base de datos? o vas a crear una tabla nueva?

Comment: Buen día, creare una tabla nueva

Comment: Rails usará sus convenciones para crear la migración y definir el nombre de la tabla, si haces un scaffold de `Product` la tabla se llamará `products`, pero recuerda que también puedes modificar manualmente la migración antes de ejecutarla.

Comment: Gracias, intente corregir a mano los nombres pero hay que ser demaciado minucioso y al parecer no es lo mío, seguiré con los nombres que me genera rails y en caso de poder usar los nombres en ingles los usaré...

Answer (score 3):

`bin/rails generate migration CreateProducts name:string part_number:string`

Generará una migración que creará una tabla Products con dos campos **name** y **part_number** de tipo **string**.

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :part_number
    end
  end
end
```

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Entiendo esa parte el problema es que al generar modelos o scaffold raíl determina automáticamente los nombres de las tablas en base a los plurales anglosajones, por lo que al crear un scaffold para publicación la migración crea una tabla publicacions.

Comment: Te recomiendo que **no** uses nombres en español para tus modelos y tablas cuando trabajes con Rails, pero si realmente quieres hacerlo (*no te lo recomiendo*) puedes enseñarle a Rails como hacer *pluralize* de tu modelo `Publicacion`.
En el archivo `config/initializers/inflections.rb` agrega una entrada usando `inflect.irregular 'octopus', 'octopi'`

Comment: Eso ayuda, gracias. De todas formas seguiré tu consejo sobre mantener las tablas en inglés.